# Making SOAP-call in PHP and setting SSL version

Tags: php, soap, ssl, curl, wsdl

I've made several scripts working with external WSDL. I have encountered one I have to integrate into our system that I can't get to work. I'be been trying for a week without any result.

The script fails on creating the constructor already:

```
$client = new SoapClient("https://webtjener09.kred.no/TestWebservice/OppdragServiceSoapHttpPort?WSDL");
```

Gives the error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://webtjener09.kred.no/TestWebservice/OppdragServiceSoapHttpPort?WSDL' : failed to load external entity "https://webtjener09.kred.no/TestWebservice/OppdragServiceSoapHttpPort?WSDL"
```

I do have openssl installed and working with PHP, and remember that I already have other working SOAP-calls to other WSDL's over SSL. I found out that I can not solve this with a cert either since it fails already at the constructor.

**But:**
I tried to connect to the remote server with openssl command line, and this command also failed:

```
openssl s_client -connect webtjener09.kred.no:443 -state
```

But then I tried forcing it to SSL3 and it worked perfectly, like this:

```
openssl s_client -ssl3 -connect webtjener09.kred.no:443 -state
```

So that got me thinking that I had to match the SSL version of the remote server. To doublecheck I also tried making a cURL connection via PHP and it failed until I added forcing of SSL version like this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
```

Adding CURLOPT_SSLVERSION to the cURL connection made it ok. And then the root of my question:

How do I force PHP soap constructor/call to use SSL3 as well. It seems to me that this would have to be the solution. But I haven't been able to find out how to set the PHP SOAP function to use SSL3 only. Since both commandline -openssl- and PHP cURL work with SSL3 forced, then I presume the same thing would happen with my SOAP-function?

Inputs, please?

(Using Ubuntu Linux, PHP 5.3.3)

Comment: Since PHP 5.5.0 It's possible to set SSL_METHOD for SoapClient, but if there is problem on trying to get WSDL file, It has to be downloaded manually via cURL for example.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem, the following wrapper solved it (i had to force SSL2)

```
class StupidWrapperForOracleServer extends SoapClient {
  protected function callCurl($url, $data, $action) {
     $handle   = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
     curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type: text/xml", 'SOAPAction: "' . $action . '"'));
     curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
     curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
     curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 2);
     $response = curl_exec($handle);
     if (empty($response)) {
       throw new SoapFault('CURL error: '.curl_error($handle),curl_errno($handle));
     }
     curl_close($handle);
     return $response;
   }

   public function __doRequest($request,$location,$action,$version,$one_way = 0) {
       return $this->callCurl($location, $request, $action);
   }
 }
```

Btw. if it fails at the downloading the WSDL file part, then download the WSDL manually (with curl for example), and use that file locally. IMHO __doRequest is not called while in the WSDL downloading stage.

```
file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__) .'/Server.wsdl',get_wsdl()); //get_wsdl uses the same wrapper as above
$oWS = new StupidWrapperForOracleServer(dirname(__FILE__) .'/Server.wsdl',array('trace'=>1,'cache_wsdl'=>0));
```

Answer (score 5):

As of PHP 5.5.0, I believe you can do

```
$client = new SoapClient("https://webtjener09.kred.no/TestWebservice/OppdragServiceSoapHttpPort?WSDL", array(
    'ssl_method' => SOAP_SSL_METHOD_SSLv3
));
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit your suggestion by explaining the benefit of SOAP_SSL_METHOD_SSLv3? What about the difference with SOAP_SSL_METHOD_SSLv23 or not providing any method at all?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of creating a wrapper, can you try to add the following code fragments?

```
$stream_opts = array(
//      'ssl'=>array('ciphers'=>"3DES" // also working
//      further ciphers on http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/ciphers.html
        'ssl'=>array('ciphers'=>"SHA1"
      )
);

$myStreamContext = stream_context_create($stream_opts);
$soapOptions['stream_context'] = $myStreamContext;
$soapClient = new SoapAuthClient("https://...", $soapOptions);
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Try 'sslv3://webtjener09....' or use a [wrapper class](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php#97029) where you can set the required cURL option.

Comment: Tried both ways, but neither works. Well, it may be that I don't have the wrapper class 100% correct. So if you have an example for me it'd be great.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oracle Weblogic 11g to host your web services under SSL, make sure you are using the JSSE-Based SSL Implementation.

Log into the Weblogic Console, and go to Server->(your server)->Configuration->SSL->Advanced and check the **Use JSSE SSL** check box.

More information can be found in the [Weblogic Manuals](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13707/ssl.htm#BABFDJGB)

Answer (score 0):

Be careful if you use utf-8 charset.
This solution works well, but  you must declare the charset in header Curl.

```
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type: text/xml; charset = utf-8", 'SOAPAction: "' . $action . '"')
```