# Connecting to https host with soapclient: how to fix SSL problems?

Tags: php, soap, ssl, https, handshake

### TLDR

I can't seem to connect to a https endpoint with a `SoapClient`. As my wget returns a `handshake failure`, I suspect that is the cause.

**How can I do a SOAP request to this server with `PHP`?**

### complete

I'm trying to connect to a SOAP server (https). It doesn't have client certificate authentication, so the connection should be pretty straightforward, but sadly it isn't.

The problem is that I keep getting `Could not connect to host` messages.

The connection method I'm using is working for another server and I've verified that I'm setting the location for this server correctly (changed it to a server I control, and I'm getting response there). I suspect the problem is with the https/ssl connection to the server.

#### Situation

- I'm creating a PHP `Soapclient` based on a wsdl I have locally.
- If I change the endpoint I get Request and Response headers, and everything works as expected.
- the machine is reachable from my server, though there is a problem visible when I use `wget` to connect to it (see below)
      Unable to establish SSL connection.
- The problem is also visible with openssl connections (see below)

#### What I tried.

There are a lot of topics about "no connection!", but there is obviously a lot of "my router was bad, I made a typo in the address etc" going on. I did try these settings that were suggested multiple times, but more as a "cut'n'paste" solution to be sure It didn't work" then out of real reasoning. Some comments from me added

Creating a `stream_context` for the wsdl options. I have tried

```
$context = stream_context_create(
              array(
                'ssl' => array(
                           'verify_peer' => false,  //default
                           'allow_self_signed' => true, //needs verify peer, tried that
                           'ciphers'=>"SHA1", // quite random.
                   ),
                'https' => array(
                           'curl_verify_ssl_peer'  => false,
                           'curl_verify_ssl_host'  => false
                          )
      )
            );
$options['stream_context'] = $context;
```

(first only the `ssl` options with `verify_peer` and `allow_self_signed`. Then I added the `https` array, then finally I added the `ciphers` key to `ssl`.)

I found a reference to [this bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50489), but 1) I'm not getting that warning, 2) it seems to be proxy-related and 3) My version shouldn't have the bug anymore. I'm running `php 5.3.10`

When I try to wget the url, I get:

```
    wget https://[[servername]]/SOAP
    Resolving [[servername]] ([[servername]])... xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    Connecting to [[servername]]([[servername]])|xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx|:443... connected.
    OpenSSL: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

If I try to connect with openssl, I get this:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect [[server]]:443 -state
CONNECTED(00000003)
SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
SSL_connect:unknown state
SSL3 alert read:fatal:handshake failure
SSL_connect:error in unknown state
3074463944:error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s23_clnt.c:724:
```

but if I force ssl3, I get an expected result

```
$ openssl s_client -ssl3 -connect [[server]]:443 -state
CONNECTED(00000003)
SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write client hello A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server hello A
**happy certificate stuff. this is good**
Protocol  : SSLv3
Cipher    : DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
**more happy certificate stuff. **
```

I have tried to add the curl-wrapper from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721788/making-soap-call-in-php-and-setting-ssl-version) with ssl_version set to 3 (as this seems to work on the `openssl` command above). That wrapper does discard some of the parameters, so I'm not sure how complete this would be. Further, I still get a handshake error, unless I explicitly set checking to false. If I do that (see below), I get an empty response.

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

#### Causes

As said above, I suspect the ssl handshake, but I have no clue how to fix it. I don't suspect issues with the wsdl or the client-creation, as the connection does work with another wsdl, the same wsdl with a different location set etc. It is purely this (https) endpoint that's giving me headaches.

#### Extra tests.

Just as the test above with the curl wrapper I tried sending a minimal soap envelope as @halfwarr seemed to suggest in the comments. Als returns an empty response.

So with above it seems that I do have a method to squeeze an `http 204` out of the server, but that's hardly success. But it could be a second problem? Not sure.

I am supposing that I need to try and force the ssl3, but I have no idea how (and this could be the wrong path as well so I'm trying to not have [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here :)

Comment: I've no idea, but is it worth trying 5.4.x, in case there's a problem with your version of PHP?

Comment: Not really. The live environment will not be moving towards that just yet. This version is still supported, so I'm not suspecting a problem (also, see the openssl stuff I just added: that still looks like the issue to me)

Comment: have you configured ssl on your system?

Comment: What do you mean by that? As you can see in the question, I can get openssl to connect if I specify '-ssl3', but not if I don't. I suspect this is a problem that php's `SoapClient` faces as well, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Have you tried to just use cURL to send the XML for a SOAP envelope and see what happens?  ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006977/how-can-i-send-soap-xml-via-curl-and-php)  

I think this will allow a easy way for you to test the ssl options without having to deal with extending soapClient and the other issues that could introduce

Comment: Hmm, interesting point! I'll try that first thing tomorrow!

Answer (score 1):

Interesting. Try adding this:

```
wget https://[[SERVER]]/soap/ —post-file=request.xml —header=”Content-Type: text/xml” -O response.xml
```

This will save the result as a file named response.xml.

Comment: I might not have been clear, but the point is to get a `SoapClient` to connect, the `wget` was just to show what the problem might be. I'll shuffle a bit in the question

Comment: https://drupal.org/node/880862

Answer (score 1):

The latest version PHP 5.5.3 will allow you to set the SSL Version. I've seen others that have been able to use a stream_context but, I was unable to get that work as well.

As a work around and fail safe, I used a catch to grab the soap envelope request (similar to what you tested above):

```
$xml = $client->__getLastRequest()
```

and send via curl:

---

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

That's allowing me to at least move forward.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled `php_openssl.dll` in your `php.ini`?

Reference:

[PHP SOAP cannot connect to an SSL WSDL source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001003/php-soap-cannot-connect-to-an-ssl-wsdl-source)

Comment: I didn't mention it specifically, but I'm using Linux :)